# calculate the sum of data from csv files with python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

now I am trying to calculate the sum of values from a csv file, and the values are in a specific column. For instance, in the following code is the data from the 11th column required, I cherish all your advice. Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
new_rows = []
df = pd.read_csv('02052018.csv')
x = df.iloc[:,6]
for row in x:
    row = [float(val) for val in row]
    row.append(sum(row))
    new_rows.append(row)
```

and here is the error:

```
File "C:/Users/AK6PRAKT/Desktop/Daten.sammeln.Aufgabe/neletxt.py", line 15, in <module>
row = [float(val) for val in row]
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

I can't figure out what is wrong with that code.

BTW, this is the format of the data from csv files.

```
2016/05/02 10:47:45,14.1,20.1,N.C.,170.7,518.3,-1259,-12.61,375.8,44.92,13.76,92.74,132.6,38.86,165.3,170.9,311.5,252.3,501.2,447.2,378.4,35.48,7.868,181.2, 2119,
2016/05/02 10:49:47,14.1,21.3,N.C.,74.34,273.5,-651.2,603.5,91.96,14.57,-21.17,89.67,123.7,32.22,150.6,202.2,296.0,297.7,509.9,409.2,353.1,36.49,20.25,635.6, 2119,
2016/05/02 10:51:48,14.1,21.9,N.C.,105.4,437.5,-349.4,-256.3,395.4,65.94,-3.818,85.26,143.8,33.52,-0.415,310.2,1.242,0.910,6.207,20.73,34.01,35.14,-12.38,526.9, 
2016/05/02 11:47:59,14.0,17.2,N.C.,1.609,0.760,0.993,-137.9,0.980,0.871,1.204,0.864,0.991,0.997,  NAN,119.4,1.037,1.782,0.588,0.893,0.043,-18.57,-7.459,3.864, 2114,
```

Comment: You mention column 11 but you use `iloc[:,6]`? iloc is 0-based so the correct syntax to get the sum would be `df.iloc[:,10].sum()`

Comment: @AntonvBR Yes, I tried such commands, and that works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do this:

```
x = df.iloc[:,6]
```

You get a Series object with floats from only column nr 6.  This already contains only floats , since pandas guessed it was float values.

So when you then do this:

```
for row in x:
```

"row" is not a row in your file, it is a value from the column x.   This float value can't be interated on in

```
   [ .... for val in row  ]
```

If you want the sum of the column nr 6, you can just go

```
my_sum =  df.iloc[:,6].sum()
```